# how to get data from a SAML authenticated URL using PHP cURL?

Tags: php, curl, single-sign-on, saml, feed

Suppose lets consider, 
I am having a URL https://example.com/news/feeds/ when this URL got hit it initiates SAML auth, if user already logged in it returns data. 
Using PHP cURL, I want to get the data from this URL. How I can do it?

Comment: Posting as a comment, as it's not really an answer... This is hard to accomplish, simply because SAML is generally done via a series redirects and form POSTs. If you trace a transaction of your login and retrieval of the news data with a tool like Fiddler you can see the complexity, and, as a bonus, with Fiddler, you can export it as a series of cURL transactions. You'll have to script around the SAML solution used paying attention to variables returned by both the site, the SP, and the IdP.

Comment: thanks Andrew for your reply